# Can I authenticate a user from a Chrome Extension via their Github account without a backend server?

Tags: github, google-chrome-extension, oauth, github-api

I am writing a Chrome extension^ and want allow users to authenticate via their Github account (targeting developers). I don't want to setup a back-end server just for authentication, because all functionalities work perfectly offline within a browser.

I have done some research. It seems that there are two options to implement OAuth without *your own* backend server:

1. Implicit grant, which [github does not support](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-integrations/setting-up-and-registering-oauth-apps/about-authorization-options-for-oauth-apps/)
2. Use some other services (e.g. Auth0)

My questions are:

1. Can I authenticate a user via their Github account without any backend server?
2. If I have to what does the authentication flow look like?

^ the tool without the authentication feature can be found [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-sequence/kcpganeflmhffnlofpdmcjklmdpbbmef?ref=so).

Answer (score 3):

I am going to answer my own question based on my research. Correct me if I am wrong in this answer.

> Can I authenticate a user via their Github account without any backend server?

Short answer is yes. But you may not want to do it. This is because in [the second step](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-integrations/setting-up-and-registering-oauth-apps/about-authorization-options-for-oauth-apps/), you need to send `client_secret` back to Github via a `POST`. Normally, you cannot POST to `Github.com` due to the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) from a regular web page. [Extensions aren't so limited](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr). Due to security reasons, you don't want to put `client_secret` in JavaScript.

> If I have to what does the authentication flow look like?

1. Users are redirected to request their Github identity.
2. Users are redirected back to your site by Github with a temporary `code`.
3. Your application (more likely backend or native app, but not JavaScript on the front-end) `POST` with `client_id`, `client_secret` and `code`.
4. Github includes the `access_toke` in the response.
5. Your app accesses the API with the user's access token.